# How do you import a .SHP into Sketch-Up?

Tags: qgis, kml, cad, sketchup

Does anyone know how to use a .SHP in Trimble Sketch-Up?

I have tried exporting to KML and CAD from QGIS, but the KML file doesn't read in Sketch-Up.

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2765/kml-kmz-generated-from-arcgis-10-open-in-google-earth-but-fail-to-import-into

Comment: Pro Version will import DXF http://www.sketchup.com/products/sketchup-pro/features/file-exchange

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@mapperz provided this answer:

http://enja.org/enjshape/

This is a great plugin and works like a charm. It is, however, very sensitive to coordinate systems, so I would suggest:

- make sure your SHP is in LAT/LON (WGS84)
- start a new sketchup document in 'metres'.

Worked for me! Thank you again, @Mapperz!

**UPDATE**

This plugin stopped working beyond Sketch-up 7, and the project's [Github page](https://github.com/enjalot/enjshape/tree/master) hasn't been updated in some time, and does not have 'issue tracking' enabled (weird.)

However, I was able to download a version of Google SketchUp 7 from [this shifty website](http://www.oldversion.com/windows/google-sketchup/), and the plugin seems to be working as described above.

Comment: This is a great plugin.  Have you been able to use the extrude by height field option?  I have tried it on a number of different files and the drop down list is always empty, even when I have attribute fields.

Comment: @RyanGarnett no i haven't...only looking at 2D parcels right now...

Answer (score 3):

I have been developing a personal open source project. I have placed it on GitHub. It works for SketchUp v14 and v15. Please make sure coordinates are in WGS 1984 Geographic Coordinates. You will also need to geo-locate your model. Right now it only supports points and polylines, but other types will be coming soon.

It is in beta, and I will place it in the extension warehouse once it has a good testing.

[ShapeImporter](https://github.com/BLipscomb/ShapeImporter)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it yet but I was looking for this and found a plugin - vaguely titled spirix_shapefile_importer that imports shapefiles into [newer versions of sketchup including sketchup 2016](https://sites.google.com/site/spirixcode/code) (plugin Ruby).