# Is there a way to export from a vector format to Collada .dae?

Tags: convert, collada

I am curious if there is a way to export from a vector format (ie: shapefile for PostGIS table) to Collada (.dae).  ogr2ogr will do to GML and KML, but not Collada.  My preference is to use open source, where at all possible.

Thanks...

EDIT QUESTION

To add a little further, I am hoping to find a way to go directly from vector to Collada.  Either with an existing tool, or building upon available libraries.

Comment: OpenSceneGraph seems to deal with Collada and shapefiles: http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Support/UserGuides/Plugins but I have not tested it myself.

Answer (score 1):

To export a vector to `Collada`, you can choose any free versions of [SketchUp](http://www.filehippo.com/download_sketchup/history). I give you this link because here you can find a lot of versions, begining with 5. (I've tested only the following versions: *7*, *8*, and *Make*. The *Make* version has enabled the Pro version, for eight hours of work).

To be able to load your kml files in SketchUp, you may use the [KML Tools plugin](http://sketchucation.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=323&t=38009). (Also, you need to register yourself as a basic forum member, to be able to download this free plugin). I have used the beta version with no problems (`ae_KMLTools_2.0.0-beta.rbz`). just rename the `rbz` extension to `zip` and extract the archive content into the SketchUp plugin directory:

[image]

Now, I'm going back to QGIS to show you my vector layer:

[image]

Just wait a moment to save my layer as a `kml` file:

[image]

Ok, it's done! Please, open SketchUp and specify your location (otherwise your import will fail):

[image]

After grabbing your location is done you may begin the `kml` import:

[image]

You will see a lot of import options, just press OK, and choose the kml file to be imported. Wait until the import is done and you'll see a summary report:

[image]

Well, the kml import is finished and you may start the `Collada` export:

[image]

You may choose your desired options, press Ok and your `dae` it's ready!

[image]

Some considerations:

- You must know that it is possible to import a [shapefile from QGIS into SketchUp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/how-do-you-import-a-shp-into-sketch-up)
- Also, there is the possibility to [import dxf in SketchUp](https://sites.google.com/site/jimfoltz/my-sketchup-plugins/freedxf)
- If using the first link I gave you in this post, you can download older SketchUp versions with dxf import embedded, removed from the current versions (I didn't test it).

Comment: Sorin thank you for the great explanation using SketchUp.  I am very aware of this process, and we are building a shapefile importer for SU.  I was hoping to find something that will directly write from vector to collada.

Comment: I wish you good luck with your shapefile importer! I'm looking forward to hear news from this project!

Comment: This workaround no longer works.  There has to be some sort of FOSS tool that converts a 3D KMZ file into a Collada file.  Any help?

Answer (score 1):

There are plugins for importing KML into the FOSS 3D modelling package Blender (a GREAT piece of software by the way.) And Blender also exports to Collada, and has a python api.
So you might be able to build something with those components.

The thing to watch out for is preserving coordinates though. Since Blender isn't explicitly a GIS, you'll have to make sure the coordinates look right along the way.

Blender: http://www.blender.org/

KML Plugin: http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.4/Py/Scripts/Import/KMZ

Obviously this is still a pretty contrived method, even if it works. The smoothest would of course be something like GDAL, but with support for Collada and Shape.