# GIS Wireframe into SketchUp

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d, arcgis-10.3, sketchup

There used to be a plugin that allowed GIS data (.shp file) to be exported and then opened in SketchUp.  This plugin no longer exists.  I have wireframe data of buildings that is 3D in ArcGIS that I need to be able to import into SketchUp so that I can then build the model from the wireframe.  Does anyone have any idea how to go about doing this?  I have ArcGIS 10.3 and SketchUp 2015.

Comment: Try this thread and my updated answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/66537/how-do-you-import-a-shp-into-sketch-up